# How to tell Chrome, please use local javascript from the browser for every site or any actions? Similar to Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dojo, chromium

I am using Chromium / Google Chrome browser in  my Ubuntu desktop. Now for some testing reason, i need to run this javascript from browser not from the website server javascript code.

Is there any way in Chrome i can attach this source, which will be executed anytime when the browser go to any web page?

```
$("#id").find("div").find("li").find("p").find("b").html(" adult scene are deleted ");
```

This does not run from server scripts, this js file i want to embed in the browser. (like i believe opera has this feature, how to do such in Chrome?)

Comment: Have a look at [user-scripts](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts).

Comment: Great, so its like Opera > settings > define the path of js file > make a browser.js file and place custom js scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a possible way to do that, but you can create a **bookmarklet** in Chrome, or any other modern browser (like Firefox). Here's how you do it:

1. Create a local HTML page with an anchor tag with the following in it:

   ```
   <a href='javascript:$("#id").find("div").find("li").find("p").find("b").html(" adult scene are deleted ");' target="_blank">The link</a>
   ```
2. Then, you drag this link into your bookmarks bar when you open the webpage in Chrome.
3. Now, when you click on this bookmark in Chrome, that will happen.

**Please note that you are using jQuery, so the bookmarklet will only work in pages using jQuery. However, you can use this code instead (but modify it and then compress it before using it):**

```
var elements = document.getElementById("id").getElementsByTagName("b");
for(var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].innerHTML = " adult scene are deleted ";
}
```